# Does my VM get deleted when i disable billing GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, billing

I have a VM Compute Engine on GCP as a SPOT instance. I stopped the instance and want to remove billing from my project (automatically when a certain budget is reached).

Does the removal of the billing delete the VM instantly? Or only after a certain time?
I have no-deletion-protection turned on.
I'm afraid of stopping the billing during a test - I don't want to loose all my data on my VM.

> Capping (disabling) Cloud Billing as described in the previous example
> is binary and terminal. Your project is either enabled or disabled.
> When it is disabled all services are stopped and all resources are
> eventually deleted.

I couldn't find anything on the immediate consequences of disabling billing on GCP. What does eventually mean?

Answer (score 1):

When you disable the billing, all your resources stop consuming money. In the cloud, CPU, memory and disk consume money.

Therefore, all your processing services, VM, Cloud Functions, Cloud Run, Dataproc, Dataflow, GKE clusters (...) are stopped.

Your data are kept (persistent disk, cloud storage, BigQuery,...) but the cost is still counted. If you want to recover your data, you will need to attach a valid billing account, pay the due fees and then get back your data.

Comment: To add to this correct answer. You can expect Google to delete your resources since you are not paying for them. Google does not provide details on when. Only use removing a billing account to prevent abuse of your services, not because you are testing and don't want to pay for the services. Otherwise, have plans (backups) in place that you will lose those resources.

Answer (score 1):

Same with this information under [enable billing](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#:%7E:text=The%20project%20was%20shut%20down%20(deleted)%20and%20then%20restored%20within%20the%2030%2Dday%20recovery%20period.) wherein once the project is deleted you have 30 days to recover your resources (VM Compute Engine). But take note of this information "If you have a project where billing has been disabled, all billable services within that project are stopped. Re-enable billing on the project to restart the resources." Meaning, you can only restart your resources once you re-enable billing. You can read the link for more information.